# how can use future in the listview flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, future, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I have future function and I want show this in the listview.seprator, but the listview do not get the future value. how can i fix this?
this is my code:
my hive class:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 3)
class TaskCat  extends HiveObject{

  @HiveField(0)
   String catName;

  @HiveField(1)
  int userId;

  @HiveField(2)
   User? user;

  TaskCat(this.catName,this.user,this.userId);
}
```

This is my function:

```
Future<List> showCategoryInHome()  async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var taskCatBox = await Hive.openBox('taskCat');
  var filtertaskCat = taskCatBox.values
      .where(
          (TaskCat) => TaskCat.userId == sharedPreferences.getInt('key'))
      .toList();
  return filtertaskCat;
}
```

and this is my listview code:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: controller.showCategoryInHome(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    Future<List> test = controller.showCategoryInHome();
    return ListView.separated(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 11 ,  // here currently I set the fix value but I want the length of my list
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TextButton(
          onPressed: () {

          },
          child:  Text(
         test[index].[catName], // and here not working too bucouse the list is future
            style: normalTextForCategory,
          ),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return const VerticalDivider(
          width: 15,
          color: Colors.transparent,
        );
      },
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: controller.showCategoryInHome(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                List data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                return ListView.separated(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount:data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        data[index]['catName'],
                        style: normalTextForCategory,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return const VerticalDivider(
                      width: 15,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Future` you have `builder`, where you can access to your future when it ready via snapshot.

I've added the precise type where to make the use of Futurebuilder easier.

```
Future<List<TaskCat>> showCategoryInHome()  async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var taskCatBox = await Hive.openBox('taskCat');
  var filtertaskCat = taskCatBox.values
      .where(
          (TaskCat) => TaskCat.userId == sharedPreferences.getInt('key'))
      .toList();
  return filtertaskCat;
}
```

And adjust your Futurebuilder to the following:

```
FutureBuilder<List<TaskCat>>(
  future: controller.showCategoryInHome(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // Check if your future has finished
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      // Here you have the result of your future, which is a List<TaskCat>
      final tasks = snapshot.data; 
      return ListView.separated(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: tasks.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {

            },
            child:  Text(
              tasks[index].catName,
              style: normalTextForCategory,
            ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return const VerticalDivider(
            width: 15,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      // Here you can show e.g. a CircularProgressIndicator
      return SizedBox();
    }
  },
)
```